# PHP elseif question

Tags: php, oop

Currently I have the following section of code:

```
<?php if($sales_pages): ?>
    <?php foreach($sales_pages as $sale): ?>
<div id ="sales">
    <span class"thumbnail"><a href="<?=base_url()?>page/sales/viewsale/<?=$sale->id?>"><img class="thumbnailImg" src="<?=base_url()?>includes/uploads/sales/thumbs/<?=$sale->thumbname?>" alt=""/></a>
    <span class="location"><?= $sale->location?></span>
    <span class="price"><?= $sale->price?></span>
    </span>
            </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

What I am trying to do is the following:

When there are 0 sales (fetched from database) in the foreach I would like my code to display a message

Is elseif the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You should use [`else`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php). It's basically the same as saying `elseif(True)`. You'll end up with something like:

```
<?php if($sales_pages): ?>
    <?php foreach($sales_pages as $sale): ?>
        Print a sale
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    Nothing here...
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can (and should) read [more about the control structures in PHP in the PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php).

Oh, and by the way. It looks like you are using [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/). Did you know that you can use the [`site_url`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) function instead of prepending stuff with `base_url()`? You'd then write the url of your link like this (although I think you have a syntax error in that part of your code above):

```
<a href="<?=site_url("page/sales/viewsale/$sale")?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ELSE.

```
$numberOfSale = //fetched from database;

if($numberOfSale ==0)
{
    //Display here your message
}
else
{
    //Loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SOME SQL HERE") or die("Could not perform select query - " . mysql_error());

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);


    if($num_rows == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
       //Loop it and use the results 
    }
```